# How to best fit image to a fixed ratio?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-images

I have a catalog of photographs most of which have aspect ratio of 4:3. There are a handful of odd ones and it is not feasible to crop those to 4:3 without losing important parts of the pictures.

I want to show all of these photographs, including the few odd-size ones, in a bounding box of the same size for every photo. The bounding box is determined by a `div` of class `col-md-4`:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <!- the image here: -->
    <img class="img img-responsive" src=" ... " />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <!- other stuff -->
  </div>
</div>
```

For those images that are already at 4:3, they all show up nicely with the exact same display dimensions, even though the image (file) sizes can be different, eg one can be of 1024x768 and another is 800x600.

For an image that is "too wide", I would like it to be displayed as (where the gray bars represent the background of the bounding area):

[image]

For an image that is "too tall", I would like it to be displayed as:

[image]

In other words, each odd size image should "choose" its height or width to fit into the bounding box depending on whether it is too tall or too fat. Is this achievable by bootstrap and css?

It may be worthwhile noting that currently, the bounding `div` has the same width set by bootstrap for every image. The height is determined by the image's aspect ratio. When every photo is at 4:3, then the heights are also all the same. So for odd-size photos, the height has to be locked at 3/4 of the display width.

Comment: Have you investigated either object-fit (or background-size) contain?

Comment: So basically you want a container with a fixed aspect-ratio (e.g. 16:9) and show the image on either full height or full with (using the AR for the other dimension) centered in that 16:9 container?

Comment: @FabianSchöner Yes, that is correct. Because the width is determined by bootstrap, so the height will also all be the same if the AR is adhered to.

Comment: @OldGeezer check my answer below, that should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use padding-top and absolute positioning (and a bit of magic) to achieve that:

```css
.imagewrapper {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.imagewrapper:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  /* this is AR of 16:9 calculated 9:16*100 = 56.25 */
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.imagewrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="imagewrapper">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x200/000/fff" alt="600x400" />
</div>

<div class="imagewrapper">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="600x400" />
</div>

<div class="imagewrapper">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x600/000/fff" alt="600x400" />
</div>
```

If you need another aspect ratio for the container change the `padding-top` value of `.imagewrapper:before`. It can be calculated by `height / width * 100` (e.g. `9 / 16 * 100 = 56.25` for 16:6 or `4 / 3 * 100 = 133` for 3:4).

**How does this work?**

The `before` Element gets 100% width of its parent and a specified percentage-based `padding-top` value (e.g. 56.25%) which makes it take 56.25% of its width as height which basically makes it a fixed AR box.

The image gets positionied centered inside this box by position absolute, top, left and the transform while its size is contained by height and width auto but max-height and max-width 100%.

You can put this inside roughly anything that changes the width of the outer element and it should work.

Similar behaviour can be achieved using `aspect-ratio` but this solution works in MSIE and other (legacy) browsers and basically everything from this millennium too.

Comment: Let me have some time to absorb this to understand how the magic works.

Comment: I added some explanation. Basically the `:before` Element brings the box around it to a fixed AR's height based on the boxes width and the image gets contained in it.

Comment: It works beautifully, but I still don't understand how `:before` applies to styling. Is the image located in the padding area?

Comment: Exactly. The `:before` element pushes its parent box to a certain height using the padding-top value. Now the box has a height (which is ar-relative to its width using the padding-top from the `:before`). Now were adding absolute positioning to the image so it hops "on top" of that padding-based space. By centering it and setting the width to the shown values it gets centered and contained in the space generated by the `:before` elements padding-top. You can what the before element actually does to the box by removing the image. Youll see the blue box with the red border stays the same size.

Comment: Another question: why is it necessary to set `top/left` to 50% and then `translate` back? If the `translate` is missing, what is the size of the image?

Comment: Setting `top` and `left` to 50% makes it move away 50% of the parents dimensions from the top/left corner. `transform:translate(-50%, -50%)` pull it back by 50% of its dimensions in direction of the top/left corner. This combination makes the image always center perfectly inside the container, no matter of the dimensions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238301/discussion-between-old-geezer-and-fabian-schoner).